# How to convert a video which was recorded using an iPhone from portrait to landscape

Tags: macos, iphone

I recorded a video using my iphone in landscape mode.  When I watch the video back on the iPhone there is no problem because I can rotate the device to watch it back in landscape mode.

But when watching it on my mac its recorded in portrait mode and my neck is sore for tilting to one side ;-) to watch it.

Any way I can rotate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends entirely on the software you are using to play the video.

I know for a fact that [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) has a built-in filter to rotate the video, so maybe you should download and install that.  It's available for pretty much every operating system, including OS X.

Comment: I want to put it on facebook though and it comes out wrong